# A fully featured floating video player which can be minimized to an icon?

Tags: applications, video, media-player

I am looking for a video player which has floating support and can be minimized to a floating icon. Ideally it should also have the option to rotate the video.
Does anyone know of something that might be suitable?
 I should add that I am aware of the video player provided in the floating apps collection. However, this video player is rather basic. (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lwi.android.flappsfull&hl=en)

Comment: Questions asking us to **find or recommend an app, device, ROM, accessory or off-site resource** are off-topic for Android Enthusiasts as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam and become obsolete quickly. Instead, [describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve](//blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping).

Answer (score 1):

Try the app **[Float Tube Video Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.awesome.floatingtube&hl=en)** or **[Floating Video Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=thanhnguyen.com.floatingvideoplayer)** or **[GPlayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gpc.myweb.hinet.net.PopupVideo&hl=en)** or [**FVPlayer-floating video player**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bringer.fvplayer&hl=en) or any other similar app from Play Store.

(All I did was a [simple Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=floating%20video%20player%20android))